# Flutter, mainAxisAlignment is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

```
Container(
        child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 60,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [Text("firstttt")],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                  "secondddddddddddddddddddddddddddddseconddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddseconddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddseconddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 40,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [Text("third")],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
```

I want the third container to be in the lowest section (in the second container height size)

but it does not work above code

how to solve this?

1st and 3rd must be diagonal

Actually, it can be solved using Stack, but I want to solve it without using Stack.

Comment: Can You please add screenshots if what You want and what You currently have?

Comment: @Josteve I added it please check it out and I want dynamic height size so, I don`t want it to be sized height

Answer (score 0):

In your top most `Row`, where You have:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
```

Use:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

Comment: Then how to drop Third one to below again??

Comment: 1st and 3rd must be diagonal

Comment: The third one is in a Column already, with the mainAxisAlignment set to end, it should be at the bottom.